# Visual Studio installer project - setting file permission

Tags: visual-studio

I've got a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) application that uses an **SQLite 3 database**.

I also have an Visual Studio installer project, that copies the database file (set-up as content file) to the application installation folder (`C:\program files\xxx\yyyy\`).

This works just fine in Windows XP but in some Windows 7 and Vista installations, my program hangs as it can't write to the database. If I manually set the database files access permission to full to all users, the problem goes away.

Is there any way, that I can have the Visual Studio installer project create this file with full permissions? Or is there a way to copy some content file to 'My Documents' from the Visual Studio installer project?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22FILE+INSTALLATION+PROPERTIES.DEFAULTLOCATION%22%29;k%28%22FILE+INSTALLATION+PROPERTIES%22%29;k%28VS.PROPERTIES%29;k%28VIEW.EDITOR.FILESYSTEMEDITOR%29&rd=true

Comment: had to add a manifest as well

Comment: So how do you resolved? The solution pointed does not treats permissions...

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10539449/847201.

Comment: The link to the answer does not work. This should be the working one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10540927/540776