# can not change folder permission during installation

Tags: asp.net, wpf

i know that people couldn't say that this is trivial, but i have search for days in internet and can not be able to do this.
i am using visual studio 2010 ultimate and have created my setup with setup and deployment of vs 2010.the problem is that i have an application folder which contains my database and which is deployed with my application. When i deploy it in administrator part of computer, all is correct, i devined that it is due to fullcontrol permission of administrator programfiles folder.But when i deploy it in another account, application don't has access to database for writting. i looked for the web site and understood that this is due to programfiles folder permission for others users.So i decide to do another research in order to give more rights to users for this folder.

I finally understood that i can achieve this with authoring tools like robocopy by using custom action or with a command line by just correctly write my custom action. After more researchs, i understood that i can do it with a command line which use robocopy and give folder permission during installation for this custom action or only with custom action.

for custom action, i tried many links, but the best link that i obtained was ([How to give Read/Write permissions to a Folder during installation using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288444/how-to-give-read-write-permissions-to-a-folder-during-installation-using-net)) without success (i change /folder="[CommonAppDataFolder][ProductName] with /folder="[CommonAppDataFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName] in customactiondata" due to the fact that product name is in my manufacturer folder").i don't understand why this code don't change folder permissions during installing and don't know how i can use robocopy or icalcs in custom action to change folder permissions during installation. my setup and others requirements have been packaged with dotnetInstaller, i dont know if i can be able to continue use it.

please, i greatly need your help to be able to do this

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem. After many trying, i understood that i was giving permission to the wrong folder because my documents and database were contained in programfile folder. after understand this, i only change the place to set permission by :/folder="[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]" and permission have been setted.