# Database not found during making setup file

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

When I run my app from the project folder in `bin\debug` or `bin\release`, it works fine. Everything as well as my database works fine.

But when I create a setup file with my debug or release files my database doesn't work. I set my database connection like:

```
SqlCeConnection compact_con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\chondrokotha.dat;Password=4545;");
```

and keeps the `chondrokotha.dat` in the debug folder.

My files look like this:

[image]

after that i put the database into a folder named chonrokotha. in this time error shows like

[image]

How can I solve this problem during creation of a setup file?

Comment: But when i copy my files into another file then run the app in that case database works fine.

Comment: I updated my question showing  the error.please check it??

Comment: Well, OK - that's a first step. So it seems to be an **access permission** problem - the file **is found** - but in the `C:\program files` directory, your current user obviously doesn't have permissions to **write** back to the database file! Try to put your database file elsewhere - under `C:\temp` or better yet: into [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of .NET

Comment: But all files including database are in the C:\program files.by the way, how can i solve this??

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, it's clear that your current user executing your application doesn't have **write permissions** into the folder where your database file resides. This is the default on Windows Vista (I believe) and higher - by default, normal (non elevated users) don't have write permissions in `C:\program files` (and that's a **good thing** overall).

You can solve this several ways:

- put the database file into a folder where the user can write to, e.g. `C:\tmp` or somewhere under `C:\Users\(username)\.....`
- put the database file into [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - a .NET mechanism that gives you folders where you are **guaranteed** that the user can write to
- create a subfolder under your program folder and give your user (or `Everyone`) write permission to that folder

Comment: in 3rd option have i give the write permission to the folder for user(everyone) in my program(in my code).if so how can i do that???

Comment: @DarkenShooter: **research!!!** You do know Google, right? Search for `visual studio setup add permissions to folder` or something like that, and then look at the articles you get.... [e.g. this other SO question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719224/visual-studio-installer-project-setting-file-permission)